# Why does assigning a list reference to an array variable in Perl work?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I have the following three assignments, of which the second one looks non-standard:

```
my $realRef = [1, 2, 3];
my @nonRef  = [4, 5, 6];
my $nonRef  = [7, 8, 9];
```

The second one should really be the following instead:

```
my @nonRef  = (4, 5, 6);
```

When printing, all three variables contain array references and especially the same named variables only differing in `@` and `$` don't share the same data or overwrite each other.

```
Ref: ARRAY(0x1fd6a8); $VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ];
Ref: ARRAY(0x6445d8); $VAR1 = [
          4,
          5,
          6
        ];
Ref: ARRAY(0x644740); $VAR1 = [
          7,
          8,
          9
        ];
```

Why is `@nonRef`containing an array reference at all? Is that stored in `$nonRef` of the symbol table entry for `nonRef` or something like that? And why do values of `@nonRef` and `$nonRef` don't overlap? Aren't both referencing the same symbol table entry only with different slots, `ARRAY` vs. `SCALAR`? Because both store references in the end, I would have expected that the same symbol table entry with the slot `SCALAR` is used.

Thanks!

Comment: Parens merely override precedence. They don't create any kind of value/variable like `[]` and `{}` do.

Comment: The official docs say so as well, even though I find the explicit first example `(LIST)` confusing. That looks like the parentheses are required, but they are not: `List values are denoted by separating individual values by commas ([...]):` https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors

Comment: They are required in the specifically mentioned situation for the reason showed in my answer. (`my @a = 4,5,6;` and `my @a = (4,5,6)` are not equivalent because of the low precedence of `,`.) The doc to which you linked is phrased misleadingly, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one is the same as `my @nonRef = ([4, 5, 6])` — that is, you're just putting your arrayref into `$nonRef[0]`.

Comment: I see. Because I used `Dumper(@nonRef)` instead of `Dumper(\@nonRef)` things looked the same as for `Dumper($realRef)`. That seems pretty confusing to me, because `@nonRef = [...], [...]` doesn't work as easily and is at least warned about. I would have preferred a compile time error.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning the `()` isn't a list constructor, it's just the usual precedence-grouping operator. When you do `@array = [...], [...]` the comma binds too loosely (i.e. `(@array = [...]), [...]`), which is why we use parens. But the mistaken one isn't invalid syntax, even if it's 99.99% useless.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a one-element array that consists of a reference to an array.

---

However many scalars you assign to the array is how many elements the array will have.

```
my @a = 4;
# my @a;
# $a[0] = 4;

my @a = 4..6;
# my @a;
# $a[0] = 4;
# $a[1] = 5;
# $a[2] = 6;
```

`[4, 5, 6]` produces one scalar (a reference to an array), so `my @nonRef = [4, 5, 6];` creates an array that contains one value (the reference).

```
my @nonRef = [4, 5, 6];
# my @nonRef;
# $nonRef[0] = [4, 5, 6];
```

Note the complete lack of parens in the above examples. Parens don't create any kind of value/variable like `[]` and `{}` do. They merely override precedence like in mathematics. They are by no means necessary on the right-hand side of an assignment to an array. The only reason we commonly see them on the right hand side of assignments is because

```
my @a = 4, 5, 6;
```

is equivalent to

```
( my @a = 4 ), 5, 6;   # Only assigns 4 to the array.
```

---

For a sub without prototypes,

```
f(@a)
```

is the same as

```
f($a[0], $a[1], ...)
```

So when you did

```
print(Dumper(@nonRef));
```

it's as if you did

```
print(Dumper($nonRef[0]));
```

I prefer to use

```
print(Dumper(\@nonRef));
```